# Placing an action anywhere on my window

Tags: qt

I have created several actions that are placed inside a context menu.
Now I would like to add these same actions to a small toolbar. The problem is
that the toolbar should be located inside a VerticalLayout (underneath another widget)
rather than in one of the dock areas. Is there a way to move
a toolbar to a custom place or to place the actions inside another container?

Answer (score 0):

`QActions` are supposed to be added to menus and toolbars only.

If I got you right there, you would like to have `QActions` placeable on normal widgets, right?

A work-around would be to implement your own `QPushButton` class. Give this class an addAction method which does the following. It adds the `QAction` as a member of the button, setting the text of the QAction as the label of the button and connecting the signal `clicked()` of the button to the slot `trigger()` of the action.

Something like this:

```
void my_button::addAction(QAction* p_action)
{
    if( pAction != NULL )
    {
        m_linked_action = p_action;

        setText(m_linked_action->text());

        connect(this,SIGNAL(clicked()),m_linked_action,SLOT(trigger()));
    }
    else
    {
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

This is just a very rough example. You need to consider a lot of things like proper disconnecting of the signal when removing an action and so on. You also have to be aware of special treatment of checkable actions and stuff like that (push button has to be checkable too and signals have to be connected...).  But I think this is a good way to start.

---

**Alternative:**
What you could also do instead of connecting, is re-implementing the `mouseReleaseEvent` of your button and call `QAction::trigger()` there. Like this:

```
void my_button::mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent* e )
{
    if( e->button() == Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        if(m_linked_action != NULL)
        {
            m_linked_action->trigger();
        }
    }

    QPushButton::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}
```

By doing it like this, you can place your button anywhere and the linked action will be triggered when clicking the button.

---

- [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html)
- [QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html)